# Using too many views in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Basically my xml file has like 100 imageviews (game board like chess) which really concerns me about performance issues for my game app. Using 100 imageviews drawn on the screen will really degrade my app performance?

Answer (score 3):

Create your own `View` which draws the bitmaps shown in the `ImageViews` itself in the `onDraw` method.

Comment: using canvas to draw views? that prevents me from using onClick listeners and making changes to the view and if i am correct canvas has to redraw itself all over to make changes in it

Comment: Then you would indeed need to implement your own onClick listeners to determine which tile was clicked. You can call `invalidate(Rect)` to only redraw the rectangle you specify.

Comment: thanks @Niek but yet i would like to know if having too many views on screen is going to make app performance really bad?

Comment: You can imagine having a lot of `ImageView`s showing the same content on different places would take up useless double resources. When implementing your own `View`, you can manage the object allocation yourself (e.g. initialize the bitmap to be drawn only once), and thus save a lot of resources.

Comment: my game board has 100 tiles(10x10) and apart from 4-5 tiles, all other have same image to be drawn over them so what do you suggest? I am thinking to draw 100 imageviews and set onclicklisteners to only those 4-5 tiles